# Windows 8 Pro with hyper-v no network connectivity after reboot

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-adapter, reboot, hyper-v

I have Windows 8 Pro workstation with Hyper-V installed and configured one virtual switch as "External", as on attached screenshot.

[image: virtual switch configuration]

My problem is, every time computer reboots, network does not work. "Diagnose" does not help, but disabling and then enabling of 'vEthernet (virtual-external)' network adapter solves the issue (until next reboot).

How to solve this permanently?